# Accept-Encoding in volley doesn't response with Content-Encoding

Tags: java, php, android, laravel-4, android-volley

I am developing a Restful Api. I am using laravel as backend (with apache) and for client I am using Android (with volley library for network communications).

In one of my call I have the following:

```
JsonArrayRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

@Override
public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
    Log.d("Response", response.toString());
    //PARSE JSON RESPONSE
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    }
}){

    @Override
    protected Response<JSONArray> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> e: response.headers.entrySet()){
            Log.d(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
        }
        return super.parseNetworkResponse(response);
        }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("Accept-Encoding","gzip,deflate");
        return map;
    }
};
```

As you can see I set `Accept-Encoding :gzip,deflate`.

When laravel receive the request, the headers exist:

```
array (
  'accept-encoding' => 
  array (
    0 => 'gzip,deflate',
  ),
  'host' => 
  array (
    0 => '192.168.1.104',
  ),
  'connection' => 
  array (
    0 => 'Keep-Alive',
  ),
  'user-agent' => 
  array (
    0 => 'Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.5)',
  ),
  'cookie' => 
  array (
    0 => 'laravel_session=,
  ),
  'cookie2' => 
  array (
    0 => '$Version=1',
  ),
)
```

But when android receive the response it doesn't contains `Content-Encoding : gzip` header, the headers that it contains are:

```
Transfer-Encoding﹕ chunked
Date﹕ Sun, 21 Sep 2014 15:15:37 GMT
Keep-Alive﹕ timeout=5, max=99
Set-Cookie﹕ laravel_session=
Content-Type﹕ application/json
Connection﹕ Keep-Alive
X-Powered-By﹕ PHP/5.4.9-4ubuntu2.4
Server﹕ Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Cache-Control﹕ no-cache
```

When I do the same request via curl:

```
curl -I -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip' url
```

it return:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 21 Sep 2014 14:46:12 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.9-4ubuntu2.4
Cache-Control: no-cache
Set-Cookie: laravel_session=
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

So, summarizing, I set `Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate`, the request is receiveb by server with that headers but when response is received by android `Content-Encoding` doesn't exist. It is not problem of my server because curl works good.

Any suggestion? thanks

**EDIT:**

I am watching data sent and received using Wireshark between android and my server. I am watching other request a part from that. This other request is made with `JsonObjectRequest` instead of `JsonArrayRequest` and with wireshark I can watch the following headers.

*Android -> Server*

```
Content-Type: application/json\r\n
Host: 192.168.1.104\r\n
Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.5)\r\n
[truncated] Cookie: laravel_session=
Cookie2: $Version=1\r\n
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate\r\n
```

*Server -> android*

```
Date: Sun, 21 Sep 2014 18:59:15 GMT\r\n
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)\r\n
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.9-4ubuntu2.4\r\n
Cache-Control: no-cache\r\n
[truncated] Set-Cookie: laravel_session=
Vary: Accept-Encoding\r\n
Content-Encoding: gzip\r\n
Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n
Transfer-Encoding: chunked\r\n
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n
```

In this request the response contains `Content-Encoding: gzip`. The only different between this request and the other is that this request uses `JsonObjectRequest` instead `JsonArrayRequest`, so cant ´JsonArrayRequest use Gzip encode?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this ?

Comment: In newers versions of Volley, It do that automatically, you only need to set the gzip encode in the apache server. I wrote a article about it: http://angelluispg.es/bitybyte/2016/05/01/gzip-y-ssl-en-servicios-web/ (Sorry, it is in spanish, maybe you understand a little or you could use a translator)